# Texture appears in render but not in game engine

Tags: texturing, game-engine

[image: It shows this in the render mode but when in the when I try the game it has no texture. Why doesn't it show up in the game engine?]

It renders like this, but when I play the game it has no texture. Why doesn't the texture show up in the game engine?

Here is the file:
http://filedropper.com/textured

Comment: You could upload your .blend file using a service like http://www.filedropper.com/ and we could look in depth. Please update your question instead of posting additional info as an answer.

Comment: Thank you so much stacker and to all others. You guys helped me alot.

Comment: @Kyouma mark his answer as answered, if it solved your question.

Answer (score 9):

It seems that you haven't unwrapped the mesh.
Change to *Edit Mode* in the 3D-View and select all <kbd>A</kbd> press <kbd>U</kbd> for unwrap.

[image]

In the texures settings select UV for *Coordinates* and UVMap as *Map*, *Projection* should be Flat by default.

Set the *Viewport Shading* to *Texture*

[image]

After that the texture should be shown in the *Game Engine*.

EDIT:

Examining your .blend shows that the texture wasn't included in the file. I replaced it with another one, the issue that the texture isn't rendered in the BGE could be fixed either by moving it into the first slot:

[image]

Alternatively you could set *Shading* to GLSL in *Properties Panel* <kbd>N</kbd> in the 3D-View in *Object Mode*:

[image]

Comment: Its still [like this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/jfLbG.png) What should I do?

Comment: It seems that the current GLSL doesn't expose such problem. Removing the first slot is the key.

Comment: I tried several options I don't know why but GLSL and Singletexture also rendered it in the BGE, multitexture seems to skip textures if an empty slot is found.

Comment: Also, BGE is currently only supporting textures of image type, not the procedural textures.

Comment: Looking further at Multitexture vs GLSL, for the texture to display in Multitexture, it needs to be assigned to the faces: Edit Mode > Select All , Image Editor > select the correct texture