# Why won't textures work?

Tags: texturing, texture-painting

For some reason, when I try to put a texture (picture) on any object, it doesn't work. Here are the steps I took to put a grass texture on a plane:

1: I made a new texture for the plane

2: I set the type to image or movie

3: I opened my Jpeg file

4: I even tried rendering, it won't show up!

Here is a screenshot of when the texture won't load:

[image]

Some other texture-related things that won't work for me (even when I follow the exact steps on a video tutorial):

- Texture painting
- Cube textures
- Skydomes (spherical maps)

Any ideas on why this isn't working? Thanks!

Comment: You're almost there, you need to unwrap your model see: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5915/texture-appears-in-render-but-not-in-game-engine/5916#5916 (ignore the game engine stuff).

Comment: It looks like you added the texture while the camera was active, so the texture isn't actually applied to the plane. Try selecting the plane, then adding the texture.

Comment: Actually, I added the camera to the scene after applying the texture.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**You have to unwrap the object and give it a *material* with the texture for it to show up.**

First you have to tell blender how to put a 2D texture on a 3D object by *unwrapping* it, which means selecting edges where the mesh will be cut to flatten it.  This is done by going into edit mode, selecting the edges, hit <kbd>Ctrl.</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> > *mark seam*, then <kbd>U</kbd> > *unwrap*.

[image]

[image]

Then you have to give it a material with the texture.

**If you are using the cycles render engine** this is done by first going to the *materials* panel of the properties view and clicking *New*.
[image]

Then switch to the *node editor* and add an *image texture* node by hitting <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> > *texture* > *image texture*.  Then add a diffuse shader <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> > *shader* > *Diffuse BSDF*, plug the *color* output of the image texture into the *color* input of the diffuse and the *BSDF* of the diffuse into the *BSDF* of the *material output*.
[image]

Comment: He's using blender render not Cycles

Comment: @BlendingJake I know, I just know practically nothing about BI, so if you want to add an answer for BI that would be great!

Comment: @HenryV you still have to give it a material using the texture paint data.

Comment: When I switch to cycles render, it won't let me add the nodes in the node editor. The options are all grayed out.

Comment: @HenryV you may have to click *use nodes* in the material panel, also make sure you click the *new material* button.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! It's the first time I've gotten textures to work!!!

Comment: @HenryV You might be interested in [this link](http://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/the-secrets-of-realistic-texturing/#.VGjwBJUtDX4) as well.