# Problems with textures in Standalone Player

Tags: texturing, game-engine

I am trying to render an object in Standalone player, but textures don't work. However, similar blend file does not have this problem. The only difference I have found is in texture mapping : mapping in problem file is set to "Generated" and in working file to "UV". I tried to switch to UV, but it requires "Map" field. I am confused, why in working file UV map is assigned and it is texture, whereas when I try to assign texture as UV map in problem file pop-up window does not contain any names, except some weird UVTex and UVtex.00. I also tried to unwrap texture in edit mode, but it didn't show any effect.

There was a similar question:
[Texture appears in render but not in game engine](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5915/texture-appears-in-render-but-not-in-game-engine) 
But it doesn't say, how to make "UVMap" map.

Could you make some suggestions, what is the root of problem with rendering in Standalone Player? And if my clue is right, how to set UV map?
Problem file : http://www.filedropper.com/problemfile 
Working file : http://www.filedropper.com/workingfile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your bump texture to work you need to change the bump method. Set it to one of the first three in the menu. Also set the space to `TextureSpace`, as for the other picture, as was said by Duarte since it is not an image but a Voronoi it will not  work meaning you have to bake it. Apart from that both embedded and standalone players work with this file on my pc.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Procedural textures and generated texture coordinates or not supported in Blender OpenGL renderer, that means you won't see any procedural textures in Blender's Viewport nor in Blender Game Engine or Standalone Player.

For you textures to work the have to be image based textures (Voronoi, Noise, Clouds etc. procedural texture wont work) and the have to be UV Mapped, that means you have to create an *UVMap Chanel*, unwrap your mesh mesh and use that UV Chanel on your texture afterwards, generated texture coordinates won't do.

Unwrapping is an involved and time consuming process, try searching for [video tutorials about unwrapping](https://www.google.pt/search?tbm=vid&hl=en&lr=lang_en%7Clang_pt&q=blender%20uv%20unwrap)

Comment: Textures here are image-based and I did UV unwrapping. It renders perfectly in Game Engine as one shot, but it doesn't work in Standalone player.